# Changing JButton text in GridLayout on ActionPerformed

Tags: java, jbutton, grid-layout

I am trying to change JButton text when clicked. Buttons are in array in GridLayout. I tried to use .setText, but NetBeans displays an error.

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Changing variables from private to final didn't help. I am a rookie in Java and I will be very gratefull for any help.

```
   package widok;

   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class Gameplay extends JFrame {

private JButton[] button = new JButton[25];

public Gameplay() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        button[i] = new JButton(" ");

        button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                button[i].setText("X");
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(button[i]);

    }

    pack();
    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How to make it work. Problem solved below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is "i", it has local context to the for loop, but the actionPerformed isn't within the same context. Because "i" is changing it can't be made final

What you can do issue the source of the action, which can be obtained from the Actionaevent, for example

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JButton btn = (JButton)ae.getSource();
            btn.setText("X");
```

Comment: I think the `button` Object might also be the problem

Comment: @NeerajJain Nope. The `button` array is defined as a private instance field, which is accessible from anywhere within the `Gameplay` class